# Getters found in the dart API doesn't actually exist

Tags: api, dart

Looking for example at the [Element](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/Element.html) class in the Dart API the getters borderEdge, className and paddingEdge don't actually exist and if used they throw an NoSuchMethod error.

Anyone knows what I could be doing wrong or what concept in the API I don't understand? I don't see any difference between the methods that do work and those who don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at [doc of the current integration build](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/). You are looking at the [doc of bleeding edge](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/).

Comment: It's interesting that the bleeding edge link is the first one that comes up when googling for 'dart element'. Perhaps the docs should have some kind of noticeable indicator that notifies users which version of the doc they are on (even better would be a dropdown that allows toggling between versions).

Comment: Makes sense! I actually saw the bleeding edge tag in the url, but I suppose I thought that everything dart was bleeding edge so I didn't really pay attention.